# Android Studio 2.2 update - import android.util.Log; not resolved

Tags: java, android, import

After an update on Android Studio v2.2. the `import android.util.Log;` does not seem to work.

I type `Log.e()` on the code and the import is not suggested as if the library is ignored by the autocompletion.. but if I use it and import the correct class it works.

[image]

How can I reimport my libraries or make a reset?

Comment: I'm not sure that updating the IDE would affect the SDK.

Comment: That looks like it's in the standard Android source. Other your other imports failing too? 

Try going to project structure and checking if the SDK is correct.

Comment: yes other import fail. The SDK seem to be correctly imported. Apparently there is a problem when upgrading if Android Studio is not open with admin privileges.